# Which is correct when allocating memory for a struct in C

Tags: c, struct, memory-management

Assuming we have a simple struct like:

```
typedef struct
{
    int d1;
    int d2;
    float f1;
}Type;
```

Which is the correct when allocate memory for a new instance of it:

This:

```
// sizeof *t == sizeof(Type) ( gcc prints 12 bytes)
Type *t = malloc(sizeof *t);
```

or:

```
// sizeof pointer always == 4 (in my case also on gcc)
Type *t = malloc(sizeof(t));
```

Which is the correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Type *t = malloc(sizeof *t);
```

This is the correct way to allocate the amount of memory needed for a new instance.

```
Type *t = malloc(sizeof (t));
```

This will only allocate enough storage for a pointer, not an instance.

Comment: +1: You have to be careful because this can work, but for the wrong reason. e.g. it can allocate a minimum of 24 bytes regardless of whether you ask for 4, 8, or 12 on one platform but have a smaller minimum on another.

Answer (score 4):

This is the correct way:

```
Type *t = malloc(sizeof *t);
```

**Why this is correct?**

Because you correctly allocate a size big enough to hold a structure. `*t` points to a type `Type`.

---

This is incorrect way:

```
Type *t = malloc(sizeof(t));
```

**Why this is Incorrect?**

`sizeof(t)` returns size of pointer and not the actual type(i.e: not the size of the structure).
What you need to allocate is size big enough to hold a structure not size equal to pointer to structure.

Note that, Size of an pointer pointing to **Any** type is same on an system.

---

**Why is the first approach better?**
With the first approach, when you change `Type`, the `malloc` automatically changes size to be the correct value, you do not have to do that explicitly unlike other ways.

Also, the important part of writing an `malloc` call is finding the correct size that needs to be passed. The best  way to do this is not to look anywhere (because that is when we make the mistake) but only at the left hand side of this  `malloc` statement. Since, it is  `t` in this case therefore the correct size will be `sizeof(*t)`.

**How to standardize use of `malloc`?**

With above mentioned correct approach there is one problem say, if we want to  `malloc` say `30 elements`. Then our  `malloc` expression becomes:

```
t = (T *) malloc(30 * sizeof (*T));
```

This is not the preferred way to write a  `malloc` expression, because one can make a mistake which entering the number `30` in the  `malloc` parameter. What we would like- irrespective of the number of elements required the  `malloc` parameter should always be the standard `sizeof(*x)` or something similar.

So here is an approach with an example:

Suppose we have a pointer `p`, pointing to a single dimensional array of `size 20`, whose each element is `struct node`. The declaration  will be:

```
 struct node (*p) [20];
```

Now if we wish to  `malloc` `20 elements` of `stuct node`, and wish that pointer `p` should hold the return address of  `malloc` then we have

```
p = (data-type of p) malloc (size of 20 elements of struct node);
```

To find the data type of `p`,  for casting we just make the variable name disappear or replace `p` with a blank.  So we now have

```
p = (struct node (*)[20] ) malloc(size of 20 elements of struct node);
```

We can't go very wrong over here because the compiler  will complain if we are wrong. Finally the size!  We just do the standard way we have described, that is

```
p =  (struct node (*)[20] ) malloc(sizeof (*p));
```

And we are done!

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(*t)`, because `t` is of type `Type*` so that `*t` points to something of type `Type`.

But I would suggest to use this instead, because it's more readable and less error prone:

```
Type *t = malloc(sizeof(Type));
```

Comment: How is it less error prone? If `Type` changes, you have to manually synchronize the `Type` for the `sizeof` operator. Failing to keep those in sync is the source of an error. That error cannot occur in the original.

Comment: It depends, I never forget to update the type because this is my style of malloc, but perhaps someone else does.

Answer (score 1):

this one:

```
Type *t = malloc(sizeof(*t));
```

you allocate memory for the struct, not for a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Preferably: `Type * t = malloc(sizeof(Type));`

Arguably, `sizeof *t` works as well and allows you to change the actual type of `*t` without requiring you to modify two separate locations, but using the type rather than an expression in the initial allocation feels more readable and expressive... that's subjective, though. If you you want to keep your options open to change the type, I'd personally prefer factoring that change into the typedef rather than the variable declaration/initialization.

Comment: IIRC for types you need the `()` for the `sizeof` operator. And then it is really preferable, I think, to use the variable in the expression. Such your are more robust when the type is changed.

Comment: @Jens, yeah, possibly... whichever is more understandable to the reader, I'd say.

Answer (score 0):

The first is correct. Second will not allocate enough memory, because `t` has the size of a pointer. 
Better yet is

```
Type *t = malloc(sizeof(Type));
```